# 'Invalid column name 'password01'

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

I am currently working on a Sign In page for a project and I am having issues with this exception. ('Invalid column name 'password01'.) I am using Microsoft SQL and here is the select statement I am using in my C# code that is throwing this exception when executed.

```
"SELECT [First Name], [Last Name], [SportID], [Occupation] FROM Employee WHERE [Username] = "
+ tbxUsername.Text
+ " AND [Password] = " 
+ tbxPassword.Text;
```

Comment: The password01 is one of the passwords used in the Employee table

Comment: your tbxUsername is vurnerable for SQL injection. See this page for some nice examples. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0926bc/sql-injection/

Comment: ... also, I hope you don't store passwords in plain text there.

Comment: Stop, start over. Use parameters, do not store passwords in plain text. If you are working in the context of a web application, look at your framework's features for authentication and account management rather than rolling your own. (And look at Dapper while you're at it for an easy, type-safe way to do SQL -- with parameters.)

Comment: You are missing the closing ".

Comment: Why are injecting your parameters and why are you storing plain text passwords? The 2 combined are some of the most common, well known, and *easiest* to address vulnerabilities; fix your code and design before you suffer major security breaches. Use parameters, and hash and salt your passwords.

Comment: Please read [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/) 
and [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: The simple answer is you need to quote the text values in the where clause: `WHERE [Username] = '" + tbxUsername.Text + "' AND [Password] = '" + tbxPassword.Text + "'";` - but that's just putting a Band-Aid on a mortal wound. The better answer is to read the other comments and use a parametrized query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I care about hashing passwords anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287597/why-should-i-care-about-hashing-passwords-anyway)